# Node scripting in command line for testing?

Tags: python, node.js, shell

I'm using Node for a lot of small JSON manipulation scripts, similarly to how one would use Python.
However, every time I want to change my output, I obviously have to edit my script file, save it, and run it using the node command.

Is there perhaps a way to directly write scripts in a "live" command prompt, similarly to a python shell / jupyter notebook?

Comment: If you simply run `node` in a terminal you get JavaScript REPL similar to Python shell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is.

You can use node [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl).

REPL stands for Read-Eval-Print-Loop and is the tool you are looking for.

See [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl) for more info.